# presentModalViewController for 4.3 support warnings

Tags: xcode, viewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have a problem in my code for including presentModalViewController in iOS 4.3 and onwards versions.

I am using the following code for using presentModalViewController and presentViewController when it is supported by iOS version.(Taken from a post @Stackoverflow)

```
 if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:^{/* done */}];
else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:)])
    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
else
    NSLog(@"Oooops, what system is this !!! - should never see this !");
```

The above works great when i test it in >5.0 and <5.0. But in my AppDelegate.m i have a check routine which detects if the application runs for the first time or not.

If yes then open a view first,different from the startup view.

```
if (![defaults boolForKey:@"everLaunched"]) {
    //NSLog(@"First run");
if([self.viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
        [self.viewController presentViewController:infoView animated:YES completion:^{/* done */}];
    else if([self.viewController respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:)])
       [self.viewController presentModalViewController:infoView animated:YES];
    else
        NSLog(@"1Oooops, what system is this !!! - should never see this !");
```

}

Apparently it is working,but i am getting a warning when the app is launched for the first time which i'm afraid it will give me unexpected errors in various devices

```
Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <ViewController: 0x689da90>.
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

May be in second condition you should ask for responding to presentModalViewController instead presentViewController

your code

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(presentViewController:animated:completion:)])
    [self presentViewController:myView animated:YES completion:^{/* done */}];
else if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(**presentViewController:animated**:)])
    [self presentModalViewController:myView animated:YES];
else
```

Comment: Hi and ty for helping.I finnaly got through this by remove 4.3 iOS support and moved to 5.0+ and using `presentModalViewController` only.